# Spring data - force merge of manytoone element when inserting main entity

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I have a bit of an annoying database layout, where I have to have a dynamic list side table which uses a natural key. And this second table should get a new entity added if it doesn't exist yet, otherwise updated.

So to say:

| citizen | city |
| --- | --- |
| id | code |
| postal_code | name |

The Citizen entity has

```
@ManyTone(cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@JoinColumn(name = "postal_code"
private City city;
```

Now when I create a new `Citizen` and `City` instance, and insert them it works fine the first time. However the second time I get a PK violation on city since there's already a city with the given code. Now what I want to achieve is that the city gets saved or updated when the citizen gets saved. (not the best example I know)

To persist I used the 'JpaRepository -> saveAll' method.

Worst case I could ofcourse first persist all cities, and then set the persisted instances on the citizen but I'd like to avoid that.

The side entities to get created/updated as passed in without first having to manually insert them myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to verify if the city exists before persist a new Citizen, and if it exists, you will need to set the City property with the object you get from the database.

Otherwise, it will try to persist a new city with the same key, and it will throw the PK violation error.

Comment: that's a bit what I'm trying to avoid doing though. I'd like to always trigger the merge behaviour for the city element in a certain sense even when creating the citizen.